# how to fix a keyboard that i just opened

Tags: windows-7

I opened a keyboard to repair it as it was not working but after opening it, I am unable to fix it back. The plastic keys have come out of their original place and I have no idea how to fix them

Comment: Different sorts of keyboards have different methods of affixing keys - your question simply dosen't have enough information for us to help you. I strongly suggest swallowing your pride, and taking a picture of your keyboard and the keys that are giving you issues.

Comment: I've done this a few times -- it's purely a matter of luck and cleverness, combined with the way the KB is put together.

Answer (score 3):

> The plastic keys have come out of their original place and I have no idea how to fix them

Use Google Image search to see where the keys are meant to go (for example, look at the placement of the <kbd>R</kbd>, <kbd>E</kbd>, <kbd>G</kbd>, <kbd>R</kbd>, <kbd>E</kbd>, <kbd>T</kbd> keys and so on).

You could probably Google for your exact keyboard model and get a picture. For me, that would be the Das Keyboard.

[image: DAS KEYBOARD]

Although my keyboard might not be the best one to look at for key placement...